# How to detect the mouseup event after a mousemove and long touch?

Tags: jquery, touch, jquery-events

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/za14jqw0/3/

HTML:

```
<div id="wrapper">
    <div id="a"></div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#a {
    width: 30px;
    height: 30px;
    background-color: red;
}
```

JavaScript:

```
$('#wrapper').on('mouseup', function() {
    $('#a').css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

The red box changes to yellow whenever there's a mouse up event.

The problem is that on touch devices, if the user touches the screen, move the finger around and wait a few seconds, the mouseup event is not fired.

How can I detect it?

Comment: Try `.on('touchend', function(){});` for mobile.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### To support touch devices you'll need `'touchend'` too.

[MDN:](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Events/touchend)

> The touchend event is fired when a touch point is removed from the
>   touch surface.

**jQuery**

```
$('#wrapper').on('mouseup touchend', function() {
    $('#a').css('background-color', 'yellow');
});
```

<kbd>**[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/t640qcer/)**</kbd>

### Caveat:

I can't find statistics regarding cross browser support, which is alarming considering the fluctuant nature of mobile browsers. If need be, you can use a libary such as jQuery mobile, which has an equivalent ['tap' event](http://api.jquerymobile.com/tap/). Remember, you can select specific modules to download using the [download builder](http://jquerymobile.com/download-builder/) to negate bloat.